# How can I toggle the mirror modifier visibility of all selected objects?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, shortcut

I'd like to toggle the *Mirror* modifier of selected object. I always do weight paint without the *Mirror* modifier but I have to check the mirrored half part sometimes. This script works fine but it is not so good.

```
objname = bpy.context.active_object.name
bpy.data.objects[objname].modifiers["User Defined Modifier Name"].show_viewport = not bpy.data.objects[objname].modifiers["User Defined Modifier Name"].show_viewport
```

This can toggle modifier with modifier name "User Defined Modifier Name" of active object but I need to pre-define modifier name to work it correctly. What I'd like to do is like this. I want to toggle all Mirror modifiers of currently selected objects.

```
objname = bpy.context.active_object.name
for modifier in bpy.data.objects[objname].modifiers:
    if modifier.type == "MIRROR":
        if modifier == False:
            modifier = True
        else 
            modifier = False
```

of course it does not work because I need to use this format to disable Mirror modifier.

```
bpy.data.objects[objname].modifiers["User Defined Modifier Name"].show_viewport
```

but I don't know how to get modifier name. Do you know how to get modifier name?

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE. If `obj = context.object` then `bpy.data.objects[obj.name]` is `obj`  there is really no need to get the name from the object then get the object via the name.

Comment: I didn't know it. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find mirror modifiers by type.**

This will toggle all mirror modifiers of all selected objects

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    mods = getattr(ob, "modifiers", [])
    for m in mods:
        if m.type == 'MIRROR':
            m.show_viewport ^= True
```

for just the context object, remove the outer  loop

```
ob = context.object
mods = getattr(ob, "modifiers", [])
# .. as above ..
```

If you only want to change those with a specific name, for example only those with name prefixed with "X"

```
        if m.type == 'MIRROR' and m.name.startswith("X"):
            m.show_viewport ^= True
```

If we have a unique and specific name

```
name = "Bob"
mod = getattr(ob, "modifiers", dict()).get(name)
```

in which case `mod` will be the modifier named "Bob" or `None` if there are no modifiers on this object named "Bob".

Note `getattr(ob, property_name, fallback)` is used in case an object does not have modifiers.  An empty dictionary was used in this case, since it has a `get` method, as do all blender collections, eg `bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")`  It is rarely the case that `objects[name]` is used as it will throw a key error if it does not exist.

Consider writing a generic method, and pass modifier type, and one of `'ENABLE', 'DISABLE', 'TOGGLE'`

Comment: thanx. it works. I will use your script with keyboard shortcut. Your script can disable any modifiers.It's super useful.

Comment: @Yokomizo If so, please consider to accept the answer, thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers